# GTK+ machine readable type data

Tags: gtk

Is there any official machine-readable schematic data for GTK+ which I could use to generate bindings?

Technically, I know that the C headers are machine-readable but is there anything lighter weight (such as JSON or XML) that doesn't require me hooking a code generator up to C parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a look to the gir files shipped with the GTK libraries. They contain XML gobject-introspection information which is AFAIK the input of the bindings generators.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection